# hi i want to view an output on a chart but there's no ouput when i clicked the button here's the code

Tags: c#

hi i am using c# and i want to view an output on a chart but there's no output when i clicked the button here's the code:

```
        try
        {
            Connection();
            sql_connect.Open();

            string s = "select count(*) from tbl_order where grand_total > " + textBox1.Text;

            sql_command = new MySqlCommand(s, sql_connect);
            sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            chart1.Series["Fast"].Points.AddXY("Product1", s);


            string sc = "select count(*) from tbl_order where grand_total < " + textBox2.Text;

            sql_command = new MySqlCommand(s, sql_connect);
            sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery();



            chart1.Series["Slow"].Points.AddXY("Product2", sc);
        }
        catch(Exception o)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(o.Message);
        }
```

Comment: You're not adding any data...

Comment: title of question is very low quality, also add more description about question

Comment: You need to add __numbers__, not __query strings__ as the values of your datapoints!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you don't read any data from the database. I'll just assume that your SQL connection is already set up correctly - probably that's what the `Connection` Method is doing? Then you just do:

```
try
{
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand($"SELECT count(*) AS number FROM tbl_order WHERE grand_total > {textBox1.Text}", sql_connect);
    var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read())
        chart1.Series["Fast"].Points.AddXY("Product 1", (int) reader["number"]);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

It's the same for the second table. If you want to know more about reveiving data from a database, take a look at this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C.